# Common interaction triggers WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I'm working in a `WPF` application with `MVVM` model. I'm validating a combobox using Interaction triggers. Now i have some 4 `RadCombobox` for which i have to write a common Interaction tirgger and pass some of the common values in `CommandParameter` so that i can validate all in a same.

Now i have written for one combobox and it works fine. Just wanted to know if it is possible.

//XAML Code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" IsEditable="True" Name="cmbSeriesColor" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Descr" SelectAllTextEvent="GotFocus" 
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMarketSeries.ColorId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Margin="2 0 2 0">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ColorLostFocus, Source={StaticResource ColorViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName= cmbSeriesColor, Path=SelectedItem }" />
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Can i make the above written Interaction trigger as a common for 4 combobox?

//View Model Code:

```
  public ICommand ColorLostFocus { get { return new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ValidateColor)); } }

        private void ValidateColor(object obj)
        {
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: you mean create a style ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck : May b or something like a template?